# Error System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to open a file that I already add to my TreeView control by clicking it twice, it should appears in a DataGridView control, when a I do it, it shows me the next error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "Book1.csv" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

At the `Direccion` variable, I'm not pretty sure, what it happening. Does any one could orient me? Please.

```vb
Public Sub TV_NodeMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TV.NodeMouseDoubleClick

        Dim NombreNodo As String = TV.SelectedNode.Text

        Dim parseCSV As String

        Dim tstSeq() As String

        Dim Direccion As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory(NombreNodo)

        'Dim x As String = Path.GetFullPath(NombreNodo)

        'MessageBox.Show(Direccion)

        tstSeqDataGrid.Rows.Clear()

        Using FileSystem As FileStream = File.Open(Direccion, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim TestReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileSystem)

            Do While TestReader.Peek <> -1
                parseCSV = TestReader.ReadLine()
                tstSeq = parseCSV.Split(",")
                tstSeqDataGrid.Rows.Add(tstSeq)
                TstSequenceLoaded = True
            Loop

            TestReader.Close()
            FileSystem.Close()
        End Using

    End Sub
```

Comment: Reading the docs for File.Open, shouldn't the 1s parameter be an Integer? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.fileopen?view=net-5.0.  An a fyi, there are a heap of pretty decent tools around for handling csv files via nugets and VS marketplace that do all this for you

Comment: Like Hursey suggest may need to check you are using the expected open routine. Minor point the link above is for FileOpen (no period). Plus the File.Open (with a period) takes four parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the `TreeView` is loaded with file names and those files are located in the directory where the code is running. You can see the value of `Direccion` in the Immediate Window. Using `Debug.Print` instead of a message box saves you from the embarrassment of forgetting to remove the message box in the production code. The `Debug.Print` will just be removed.

I returned an array of lines in the file with `ReadAllLines`. Then loop through the lines as you did.

With Option Strict On (as it should be) you need to add the lower case `c` following `","` so the compiler knows you intend it as a `Char` not a `String`.

```
Public Sub TV_NodeMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TV.NodeMouseDoubleClick
    Dim Direccion = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & TV.SelectedNode.Text
    Debug.Print(Direccion)
    tstSeqDataGrid.Rows.Clear()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(Direccion)
    For Each line In lines
        Dim tstSeq = line.Split(","c)
        tstSeqDataGrid.Rows.Add(tstSeq)
    Next
    TstSequenceLoaded = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Mary, it is working well already!